# Windows 7 Installation via USB on MSI GV62 8RD-200US: CD/DVD device driver is missing

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, usb-3, windows-installer

No matter what I try, I can’t seem to get Windows 7 installed on my MSI GV62 8RD-200US laptop. It’s brand new and came preinstalled with windows 10. I want to dual boot it with Windows 7 because I absolutely refuse to use 10. The problem is right when you try to install, it gives an error regarding CD/DVD drivers.

I tried two ISO images and burned them to a USB 3.0 flash drive. I’ve tried the same flash drive in a 2.0 port. Same error. I have tried slipstreaming the USB 3.0 drivers from Intel and that still failed. I tried slipstreaming them using different programs. PowerISO, Command Prompt (using the DISM command), and NTLite. All of them failed. When they fail, I try again using the 2.0 port which also fails.

I spent all day yesterday at my desk trying to get this thing to work to no avail. Today I tried Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) User Interface and Driver and that failed also. (I slipstreamed three drivers total in one ISO and it it did not work.

Keep in mind that this laptop has no optical drive and I don’t have an external one (and I really don’t feel like buying one).

----------------A few other things----------------

I tried three drivers from Intel (first link has two)

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/65855/Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22194

Laptop specs:
MSI GV62 8RD-200US

Intel i5-8300H @2.30 GHz 4 Cores and 8 Threads

8 GB RAM

NVidia GTX 1050 Ti

---

I have repeatedly tried over and over and I keep getting the same error. When I say I tried all day, I mean it. I have spent hours reading through other forums, watching YouTube Videos, burning ISOs to different flash drives, reformatting flash drives, configuring BIOS settings, everything.

Could it be that Windows 7 is not compatible with newer CPUs? If so, is there anyway to get around that?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to enable legacy boot in BIOS?

Comment: @Alex Not a good idea if the intention is to dualboot with a (UEFI mode installed) Win10.

Comment: Give the official Microsoft media creation tool a chance. Or, better, get used to Win10 because Win7 is in its last legs. Or, even better, ditch Windows altogether and use a Linux distro like Ubuntu.

Comment: Try this: "When Windows is asking for driver, just click Cancel. You will be brought back to the welcome screen. At the welcome screen, remove your USB drive, insert it back to DIFFERENT USB PORT. Click Install Now again. The installation process should conitnue. "

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Could u explain why it isn't a good idea to try legacy mode?

Comment: @Alex Because any OS installed in UEFI mode will NOT boot with "legacy" and vice-versa. In practical terms it's no dual-boot at all, just a mess and wasted drive space.

Comment: @user3104667 It's also a very bad idea to use Win7 in this laptop. MSI does *not* support other than Win10 64bit for this hardware and it's kinda obvious its hardware really requires a modern OS. If you wanna try Win7 you're on your own and, if even possible to install and run it it will be ridiculously hard to make most of the hardware work.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  then probably I do have some unique computer then, that do dual booting with turned legacy mode, even it comes with preinstalled Win10 with UEFI mode enabled. BTW, regarding any OS, - Ubuntu, FreeBSD... installed in UEFI mode somehow also can boot on other computers with legacy mode enabled, probably also "unique"....

Comment: @Alex If the setting is "UEFI+Legacy" then the firmware will first try one then other. "Legacy only" prevents ANY UEFI installed OS from booting and vice-versa. Yes, LInux distros are way more flexible but that doesn't mean you shouldn't care about doing things right from the start. That means avoiding "legacy" unless the OS doesn't support UEFI. And also there are some "unique"cases where both mode are required and many UEFI implementations that are flawed to the core. This in itself does not/should not justify giving bad suggestions to other users.

Comment: Have you tried Windows 7 in a VM? See https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/installing-windows-7-on-a-virtual-machine/ Although, since MS is doing what it can to retire v. 7 (and XP), think about testing Linux, as @GabrielaGarcia suggests.

Comment: I’m aware of using VM and Linux. However, I need to run software that isn’t compatible with Linux (yes, I know what Wine is) I might use a VM, but I really would like all of the system resources (hence the reason why I want to dual boot).